# Why is MassTransit creating two addresses and queues when my API configure my consumer?

Tags: masstransit, activemq-artemis

I am using latest MassTransit.ActiveMQ nuget 8.1.0 and .NET core 7 API. API I starting up and we are using ActiveMQ Artemis so we call `EnableArtemisCompatibility()`. It works fine.
What we want is publish/subscribe where we use a topic for publishing messages (events in MassTransit naming conventions) to subscribers/consumers.

Now we need to have more control over queue naming because of environment and permissions (prefix). Also preferable that only multicast queues are created for consumers since we only using publish/subscribe (we are not interested in ordinary send-listen-queues).

We set up host like this in API (as MassTransit Hosted Services)

```cs
configurator.UsingActiveMq((context, cfg) =>
{
    var configuration = new ConfigurationHostSettings(new Uri($"activemq://{options.Host}"));

    configuration.TransportOptions.Add("transport.useInactivityMonitor", "false");

    configuration.Username = options.User;
    configuration.Password = options.Password;


    cfg.Host(configuration);

    cfg.EnableArtemisCompatibility();
    cfg.SetConsumerEndpointQueueNameFormatter(new RgsQueueNameFormatter());
    cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
});
```

What happens when we startup API is:

- Ordinary queue is created for message (JournalHasBeenViewedMessage in image below) with same name as message and not through `RgsQueueNameFormatter` formatting. This queue creating seems unnecessary for us since we would only use consumers/subscribers for that topic.
- Virtual Topic queue is created (perfect) for consumer with `RgsQueueNameFormatter` formatting (perfect again! - the rgs.Virtual... queue in image below), but it's now anycast and should be multicast!

If we remove the `RgsQueueNameFormatter` in configuration the rgs.Virtual...etc queue is created as multicast but then without name formatting. Its then named Virtual...etc

How do configure so we can have one queue (related to virtual topic) listener for that Topic that is Multicast with correct naming formatting. And Artemis is not creating the anycast queue for us that we do not use.

This is our console after we startup our consumer for message JournalHasBeenViewedMessage

[image: Activemq console]

Comment: Without an explicit example, broker topology view, and debug-level startup logs, I really have no clue what you're experiencing.

Comment: I've got a few questions about the terminology you're using here. First, when you say "API" what do you mean? Typically an API is just an programming _interface_. It doesn't do any actual work. Second, what do you mean by "virtual queue" in ActiveMQ Artemis? There's no such things as a "virtual queue" in ActiveMQ Artemis.

Comment: @JustinBertram Sorry I ment Virtual Topic https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/migration. When Consumer starts up it creates two queues. One Anycast queue named after event. And the other queue is named VirtualTopic...etc

Comment: @ChrisPatterson thanks for replying. I uploaded a view of our console and made some text adjustments in question. Still confused? Let me know! What we would like to achive is that consumer only creates ONE durable queue and not two queues.