# How to create consumers/subscribers under a specific address in Masstransit/ActiveMQ

Tags: masstransit, activemq-artemis

I struggle with Masstransit and ActiveMQ Artemis using Masstransit.ActiveMQ nuget package in a .net core 7 project.

The problem is that the ActiveMQ Artemis server is setup and constrained so that our system can only do operations under a specific address. Under this address (`rgs`) we have full access rights.

But with Masstransit/Artemis Topology it creates queues and address Virtual.SomeOrderReceived (image below)

How can we configure so these consumer queues are configured beneath address `rgs`?

[image]

I'm well aware of publish subscribe pattern and breaking the Topology conventions may result in messy configurations that may lead to using Filters etc. But [my last question here at Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76970073/why-is-masstransit-creating-two-addresses-and-queues-when-my-api-configure-my-co) was too "wide," and I've tried to narrow this down to just this specific problem.

Really appreciate all help we can get. We are a large team working in a project where we have mostly worked with Azure Service Bus. Finding documentation or examples with ActiveMQ Artemis using Masstransit has been challenging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one queue, configure one receive endpoint and put all your consumers on it.

https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration#receive-endpoints

```cs
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.AddConsumer<SubmitOrderConsumer>();
    
    x.UsingActiveMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        // ...

        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("rgs", e =>
        {
            e.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;

            e.ConfigureConsumer<ConsumerA>(context);
            e.ConfigureConsumer<ConsumerB>(context);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This answer really helped! What we want here is that if a message is published and several consumers are listening, we would like each consumer is getting a durable queue  created. But I am aware of that we would probably need to implement filtering so that each consumer only get a message copy if filter conditions are true.